# Save and load object data with NSKeyedArchiver - data loss after object variables changed

Tags: arrays, swift, data-structures

I am using `NSKeyedArchiver()` for saving and loading objects in Swift.

The problem is when the object variables change, like adding new variable into object, the NSKeyedArchiver() cannot decode the last saved objects.

```
func tripsDataFilePath() -> URL {
    return getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("Data.plist")
}
```

The code I am using for saving:

```
func saveData() {
    NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(data, toFile: dataFilePath().path)

}
```

and the loading code:

```
func loadData() {
    if let data = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: dataFilePath().path) {
        project = data as! [Project]
    }
}
```

Is there any way to prevent data loss (can't load last objects) for when changing the object structure?

It is not important when developing first version of iOS app. But imagine that users downloaded the application and in new versions I want to add new features that requires changes to current data objects! then users will loss all datas.

Comment: Could you use the NSKeyedArchiver instead?

Comment: Feel free to handle the appropriate error rather than printing a generic literal string (there are several distinct errors the decoder can `throw`) and write a logic to migrate older versions.

Comment: You asked if it will handle data loss. I believe it does. We use NSKeyedArchiver in our app and never lose data on upgrades. However you will have to migrate data appropriate and provide default values for new fields you add.

Answer (score 0):

i have find out that the problem is with file format.

i have used this name for saving NSKeyedArchiver Object : "Data.plist"

and when i have removed ".plist" format, the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check how you decode your data. I was decoding all the data with decodeObject. However, from swift 3.0 you need to be specific how to decode your data. For example, if your data is an Integer, instead of using

let number = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: CodingKeys.number) as? Int

you need to use

let number = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: CodingKeys.number)